# EC2 AMI built from Ubuntu 18.04 with ubuntu-desktop installed is unreachable

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-ami

I am trying to create a custom AMI with some software installed including the package called `ubuntu-desktop`. However, installing this package makes the resulting AMI unusable.

Exact steps for a minimal repro:

1. Create EC2 instance from AMI `ami-0f65671a86f061fcd` (this is Canonical's Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type)
2. SSH into the box and run two commands:

   - `sudo apt-get -y update`
   - `sudo apt-get -y install ubuntu-desktop`
3. From EC2 console, right click the instance, and hit `Image > Create Image`

   - Fill in name/description, but make sure to *not* to check "No Reboot"
4. Create a new instance from that AMI that you just created

Expected result:

- New instance is created, passes all status checks, and you can SSH into it.

Actual result:

- New instance is created, does not pass the reachability check, and times out upon trying to SSH.

---

The system log in the instance launched from the AMI shows:

`[   12.125396] cloud-init[691]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 running 'init' at Fri, 09 Nov 2018 02:15:09 +0000. Up 11.47 seconds.
[   12.145064] cloud-init[691]: ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[   12.161038] cloud-init[691]: ci-info: +--------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
[   12.180149] cloud-init[691]: ci-info: | Device |   Up  |  Address  |    Mask   | Scope |     Hw-Address    |
[   12.192161] cloud-init[691]: ci-info: +--------+-------+-----------+-----------+-------+-------------------+
[   12.209635] cloud-init[691]: ci-info: |  eth0  | False |     .     |     .     |   .   | 0a:6a:25:9c:47:cc |[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Initial cloud-init job (metadata service crawler).
[   12.223002] cloud-init[691]: ci-info: |   lo   |  True | 127.0.0.1 | 255.0.0.0 |  host |         .         |`

SO formatting makes that unreadable but the interesting part is that `eth0` is not `Up`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had this exact same problem with Ubuntu 18.04 on AWS. This answer resolved it for me:

> The correct way to do it is to use an empty /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf that will overshadow/overwrite the one in /usr/lib – solsTiCe Jan 2 '17 at 13:41

This answer is from this Ask Ubuntu question:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/838865/network-manager-refusing-to-manage-wired-interfaces

Comment: I gave up and used 16.04 instead, but will try this again next time I set up Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks stackoverflow for being there. :)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to post this as a comment (because the other answer is correct) but I can't because I don't have enough reputation.

Anyway the exact command I entered was:

```
touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
```

And I was then able to SSH in.

This was taken from this comment 6 on this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1638842/comments/6